# Spring property holder from database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am planning to take my some of my values from db like.

The value will be stored like key value pair in DB(same like properties file).

Could you please let me whether spring has any support for storing key value pair in db like spring property holder?

Comment: Could you elaborate the problem statement. What do you mean property holder from DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own by extending [org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractMessageSource.html) and injecting your DAO or using your Hibernate domain class(es) to resolve the messages and then registering it as your messageSource bean in your application context.